# returning the result of anonymous callback in d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

i am calling a REST that returns json from my d3 javascript. I need the value of 'rate', which is produced by the anonymous function to be returned to whatever's calling getJSON.  How do i accomplish this? The anonymous function is a call back function that gets executed AFTER the REST call is made. this is my code that doesn't work:

```
function getJson() {
d3.json('http://something.org/api/latest.json, function(data){
var rate = [{key:1, values:[{"label":"label","value":20},{"label":"label2","value":2}]}];
    for(var key in data.rates){
        if(data.rates.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            //need to return this variable after for loop to whoever's calling getJson
            rate[0]["values"].push({"label":key,"value":data.rates[key]});
        }
    }
    //rate is fully populated here

});
//can't access populated rate anymore
return rate;
```

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. You need to run any code that needs the value from the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lars is correct. Basically the data needs to be processed within the anonymous function. So is the graph. They need to be written from within the anonymous function using the data(or response variable provided by the callback). After that, call the renderer. 
Details can be found here http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=487